# touch : File C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\touch.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: node.js, reactjs, backend

I'm a beginner of learning react and Node.js. When I run touch 'index.js' command in server, It shows
'touch : File C:\Users\sandu\AppData\Roaming\npm\touch.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- touch server.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess'
  ```

I want to know the reason to happen this.

Answer (score 2):

I tried following also. It also gave me solution.
Run below three commands in command prompt.

set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

Get-ExecutionPolicy

Get-ExecutionPolicy -list

Answer (score 1):

Sanduni it seems like you need to set execution policy to `RemoteSigned` on your Powershell. Just run following command on your powershell.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy –ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Comment: worked for me. Thank you very much Mr. Bayarjargal.

Answer (score 0):

nodemon src/index.js
nodemon : File C:file_location\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled
on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- nodemon src/index.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

when this type problem occur you can run this 3 commands on terminal

```
set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
Get-ExecutionPolicy
Get-ExecutionPolicy -list
```